# Class method returns bool, but compiler is treating it like a void return

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, return-type

*EDIT*

Still don't know what the problem is. Seemed allot like I had multiple files, but sure I didn't. Anyway, I renamed my class .h and .cc filed, and renamed the classes themselves. Didn't actually change any code, but now the problem is gone.

I would like to get rid of this question as I cant see it helping anyone in the future. Obviously was a local mistake of mine.

I am calling a method from my main function and using the boolean return in an if statement. The method is declared as a bool return, but the compiler seems to think its a void return. I've tried changing to bool to int and changing the if evaluation, but the compiler still seems to think its a void function. I have no idea what's wrong.

method deceleration inside class definition (as public)

```
       bool check_online();
```

method definition inside class cc file

```
bool Icarus::check_online()
{
        char ret = 0x00;
          //check if bluetooth adapter exists
        if(! input)
        {
                mvwaddstr(feedback,1,1,"COULD NOT OPEN rfcomm0 FOR SERVICE");
                wrefresh(feedback);
                getch();
                return(0);
        }
              //check if Daedalus is online
        if(send_cr())
        {
                mvwaddstr(feedback,1,1,"Daedalus is Online        ");
                wrefresh(feedback);
                return(1);
        }
        else
        {
                mvwaddstr(feedback,1,1,"Daedalus is Offline       ");
                wrefresh(feedback);
                return(0);
        }
}
```

calling the method in main.

```
if(driver.check_online() == false)
{
        getch();
        cleanup();
}
```

resulting error

```
$ g++ -g icarus.cc main.cc -o icarus -lncurses -lpthread
main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cc:34:30: error: invalid operands of types ‘void’ and ‘bool’ to binary ‘operator==’
```

I understand what the compiler error means, but I dont understand why its being thrown up. The function is clearly a bool return. Any help?

Comment: Show us more context. Show us the full declaration of the class, the variables in use.

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong in what you've posted. There might just be a silly mistake. Things to try/check: (1) adding flags like `-Wall -Wextra -pendantic` to see if any warnings are hintful; (2) make sure that you're modifying/saving the source-file that you think you are (e.g. by running `less icarus.cc`); (3) make sure the error is referring to the line that you think it is; (4) make sure your `main.cc` is including the same class-declaring header that your `icarus.cc` is.

Comment: Why don't you change e.g. return(1); to return true;

Comment: Is driver of type Icarus??

Comment: Show us an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), please. [Here](https://ideone.com/UTT74F) is an example of an SSCCE. As you see, it works fine, so you have to narrow the problem down or show us more code.